# Group UIButtons by UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView with two cells that have two buttons in them. The cells need to be independent of one another. Both Button1's will be selected by default. I need to be able to toggle the buttons in the same cell without affecting the other cell. For example, if I click on Button2 in Option2, Button1 will be deselected in the same cell while Option3's buttons remain unaffected. The code I have to create the buttons within the UITableView is below. The selector would toggle the buttons. And each cell would execute a different method based on which button is selected. How can I group the buttons based on the cell that they are located in?

[image: UITableView dropdown with UIButtons]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *menuId = @"OptionsMenu";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:menuId];

  if (cell == nil)
  cell = AUTO_RELEASE([[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:menuId]);

  cell.textLabel.text = [self.options objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Option2"] || [cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Option3"]) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 80.0f, 30.0f);
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button2 setTitle:@"Button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button2.tag = indexPath.row;
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(300.0f, 5.0f, 80.0f, 30.0f);
    button2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    button2.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    button2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    [cell addSubview:button];
    [cell addSubview:button2];
  }

 return cell;
}
```

Comment: What about SegmentedControl ?

Comment: I have not thought about that. I will definitely look into using a SegmentedControl. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the cell the target of the control actions, not the table view.  Then you can make the tableview a delegate of the cell.  When the cell receives the `setState:` message, you have the cell tell the tableview via the delegate.  You pass a pointer to the cell as part of the delegate message, and now the tableview knows what item to update in the model via [`indexPathForCell:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForCell:).